# Are there any command line IRC clients that use readline?

Tags: readline, irc, irssi

I'm currently using `irssi` as my irc client, which is ok, mostly, but there are a couple of things that would make the chat experience better:

1. `readline` support -- the ability to use `vi` key bindings in chat like I do *everywhere else* would be good.
2. Tab completion on nicks that *doesn't* add a space after the nick, so that I can add punctuation without hitting the backspace key.

I tried googling for `IRC readline`, but the results were [disappointing](https://www.google.com/search?q=irc%20readline&oq=irc%20readline). Does anyone know of a commandline irc client which has readline support, or know of a way to configure `irssi` to use it?

Comment: Just some pointers: vim mode for irssi: https://github.com/shabble/irssi-scripts/tree/master/vim-mode and also some more alternatives  http://superuser.com/questions/243625/any-irc-clients-with-vi-key-binds and for something completely different http://micropipes.com/blog/2012/04/09/10-years-of-irssi-use-and-i-switched-to-weechat-last-weekend/

Comment: No, I don't know

Comment: You might want to try at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @roaima Only for the other client bit, not for the configuring irssi bit. And anyway the question is on-topic here (and more likely to be answered here, for that matter).